# Share DVD/CD Drive from MacBook Pro to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, dvd, compact-disc

I have an HP Envy laptop, but doesn't come with a DVD/CD drive. I want to install games from DVD.

I know that MacBook Airs are able to use DVD/CD drives from other computers. Can I get my MacBook Pro (less than a year old) to share it's DVD/CD drive with Windows 7 on my HP Envy?

Also, the external DVD/CD drives are spendy, so, if this is possible that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy all the data from that CD/DVD on a flash drive or any other external drive (it's also possible to burn an image of the disk) and then you'll be able to copy it to any notebook you want.
Also you can share your DVD-ROM device with all computers in your network. Just go to Application/Preferences/Sharing and mark DVD or CD sharing.